# Probability of two people being born on the same day of the week

Tags: probability

What is the probability of two people being born on the same day of the week?

I understand both of them individually have probability of 1/7 to be born on a certain day and that the two probabilities are independent of one another. So the answer could be 1/49. But that's a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to sum up the days.

Let $A$ be the day that the first person is born on and $B$ be the day for the second person.

\begin{align}
Pr(A=B) = \sum_{i=1}^7 Pr(A=i)Pr(B=i)=\frac17
\end{align}

Comment: Why do I have to sum up the days?

Comment: It could be Monday, it could be Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: @user233991: A similar problem (but using 6 instead of 7) is the probability two fair dice will show the same number. That problem is found in many elementary probability books, and the answer is 1/6.